# Right use of docker volume for node-red

Tags: docker, persistence, node-red, volume

I'm currently working with node-red docker container. To install and keep additional nodes I re-use the existing image.

Now I learned that the "right" way for persistence is to use docker volumes.

What would be the right way to setup and use volumes for installing and keeping node-red nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Mount a volume on to `/data` in the container and the flow and any additional nodes installed (via the Manage Pallet option) will be persisted.

Details can be found in the Node-RED docs [here](https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker#managing-user-data).

e.g.

```
docker run -it -p 1880:1880 -v /home/pi/.node-red:/data --name mynodered nodered/node-red
```

Comment: Unfortunately manage palette doesn't work because I'm behind a proxy and need to add credentials. Environment variables work for me only if I open a bash in the container, set http_proxy and then run npm install. Up to now I failed to add these environment variables permanentely  to the container.

Comment: That will still work. You will need to extend the image to set the environment variables permanently. That page also has detail on how to extend the image (https://nodered.org/docs/getting-started/docker#dockerfile-which-copies-in-local-resources) Or you can just pass the environment variables in on the Docker command line https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: It seems, that the -e switch cannot be applied with docker start. Would the behavior of docker run ... -v ...:/data be totally consistent with docker start -i my_existing_container?

Comment: I tried all versions of    sudo docker run --rm -it -p1889:1880 -e HTTP_PROXY=MY_PROXY_CREDENTIALS -e HTTPS_PROXY=MY_PROXY_CREDENTIALS -v /home/nruser/docker/volumetest/containerdata:/data --name volumetest nodered/node-red       as soon as i try to install something over manage palette I get an error that palette infos could not be loaded :-(

Comment: The Proxy stuff is not related to the original question, please as a new question or ask on the Node-RED Slack where this can be discussed properly. Please mark the volume answer as accepted.